# If every continous function $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ has its image as an interval, then $X$ is connected.

Tags: analysis

To prove by contradiction, suppose $X$ is not connected. Then $X$ can be written as a union of two nonempty disjoint open set $U$ and $V$. Then can I assume that there exists a continuous function from $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$, please?

Comment: There is not necessarily an injective function from $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$; for if the cardinality of $X$ is strictly larger than that of $\Bbb{R}$, there are *no* such functions.

Comment: You don't need one-to-one. Define a continuous function on $X$ that takes on precisely the values $0$ and $1$.

Comment: There you go. Now prove it's continuous.

Comment: If I defind $f(U)=1$ and $f(V)=3$, is f a continuous function, please?

Comment: @user106035 For every choice of open subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}$, $f^{-1}(A)$ can only be one of four sets: $\emptyset, U, V$ or $X$. All of them are open by definition/assumption. As a result, $f$ is continuous (the topologist definition of continuous).

Comment: If $f(U)=\{1\}$ and $f(V)=\{3\}$ for $U,V$ open in $X$, non-empty and $U\cup V=X$, then $f^{-1}(D)$ for $D$ open in $\Bbb R$ will be open, as either $1\in D,3\notin D$ therefor $f^{-1}(D)=U$, or $3\in D,1\notin D$ therefor $f^{-1}(D)=U$ or $f^{-1}(D)=\emptyset$ or $f^{-1}(D)=X$.